# why can't I navigate using the child element in this xpath expression?

Tags: xslt

In XSL 2.0, I'm trying to iterate through some data by the distinct values, and then do something with them.

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(InvoiceLine/Service/ServiceMnemonicCode)">                
  <xsl:variable name="mnemonic">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:variable>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="InvoiceLine/Service[ServiceMnemonic=$mnemonic]/ServiceDescription"/>                      
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However I end up with the following error:

```
XPTY0020: Axis step
 child::element({http://schemas.blabla.com/etp/invoice/types}InvoiceLine, xs:anyType)
 cannot be used here: the context item is an atomic value
ailed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

I've bee googling furiously, and I do see people complaining about "atomic values" but I haven't seen anyone suggest what to do about it. I've using Saxon9. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This page seems to help a bit:
http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic3882.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if its the best solution, but this seems to work:

```
<xsl:template match="Invoice">
        <xsl:variable name="invoice">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <fo:table border="0.5pt solid black" text-align="center">
            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(InvoiceLine/Service/ServiceMnemonicCode)">
                    <xsl:sort/>
                    <xsl:variable name="code">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="($invoice/node()/InvoiceLine/Service[ServiceMnemonicCode=$code]/ServiceDescription)[1]"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </xsl:template>
```